# Migrating solid state drive to new machine

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I had a solid state drive running Snow Leopard in a 15' Macbook Pro, unfortunately I fried the logic board and got a new computer. I'd like to use the SSD in the new computer (which is set up to run 10.8).

Is this possible? What is the best way to get my old solid state drive running in the new Macbook?

[**edit**]: I tried booting the new machine with the old SSD and it refused to book, playing three beeps over and over.

Comment: is it an aftermarket SSD or an Apple?  What model is the new machine?

Comment: Are you trying to use the SSD as the primary drive in the new computer? What model is the new MacBook? (The MBP with Retina Display can't fit a standard laptop-size SSD, for example)

Comment: Aftermarket SSD and I am trying to use it as the primary drive.

Comment: The new machine is a Macbook Pro 13'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the drive fits, you should be able to insert the drive in the new Mac and see if the OS is capable of booting. I would make a good backup of the contents of the drive before starting if you can.

If you wanted to be safe, you could use Internet Recovery to install the OS on op of the drive or even wipe it clean and migrate things at a later date.

The drive will either physically fit and be a SATA device or not. The data part of things will be driven by your backup situation and comfort with spending time testing the OS or running a new install to ensure the drivers and OS are proper for the new hardware.

The symptom of three beeps means that the machine has not even completed the POST where RAM is checked, so you will want to first resolve whatever hardware issue is preventing the machine from completing the power on self test (POST).

Comment: Sorry - I tried booting it and got three beeps at the white Apple screen. I should have mentioned this before, sorry.

Comment: Do you have any bootable media? A clone drive on USB, a DVD, memory stick?  You need to check the machine is seeing the drive, if you have a caddy I might be tempted to boot from the original MBP13 drive, and connect the SSD via USB, check it's good to go.  If it is, I'd be sticking a new ML install over the top of the SL install.  Obviously, as bmike says, make sure you have a backup of important data.